# websocket on HTTPS

Tags: symfony, ssl, nginx, websocket

In local server i donot face this issue, but in production server with has https it does not work

```
Firefox ne peut établir de connexion avec le serveur à l’adresse 
wss://kergafa.com:8081/.
```

I have tried multiple time but could not find/understand Where the problem lies?

**my conf.yml**

```
gos_web_socket:
   server:
      port: 8081 #The port the socket server will listen on
      host: kergafa.com #The host ip to bind to
      router:
         resources:
            - '@SkiesAdherentBundle/Resources/config/pubsub/routing.yml
   client:
      firewall: main
      session_handler: '@session.handler.pdo'
   pushers:
   wamp:
      host: kergafa.com
      port: 8081
```

when I start the server:

```
[2017-01-06 04:33:12] websocket.INFO: Starting web socket
[2017-01-06 04:33:12] websocket.INFO: Register periodic callback Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Periodic\PdoPeriodicPing, executed each 20 seconds 
[2017-01-06 04:33:12] websocket.INFO: Launching Ratchet on kergafa.com:8081 PID: 7698
```

so its works

**ctunnel conf**

```
[websockets]
accept = 8080
connect = kergafa.com:8081
```

it says:

```
 [Started: /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf] stunnel.
```

the grep 8080 result

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7694/stunnel4
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your post. In the config.yml you have this:

```
router:
   resources:
      - '@SkiesAdherentBundle/Resources/config/pubsub/routing.yml
```

But that looks wrong. I think a simple change:

```
router:
   resources:
      - @SkiesAdherentBundle/Resources/config/pubsub/routing.yml
```

Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: U have right its  a mistake of the copy / paste, but its not my problem. Thank's